# date range doesn't update data

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

When I change the date range input (the "to" date from 02/01 to 01/01) the data doesn't change.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "George"
date: "12/3/2018"
output:
    flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(flexdashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)


dates <- c("01/01/18 1:00:00 PM" ,"01/01/18 1:01:00 PM",
           "01/01/18 1:02:00 PM" ,"01/01/18 1:03:00 PM",
           "01/01/18 1:04:00 PM" ,"01/01/18 1:05:00 PM",
           "02/01/18 1:06:00 PM" ,"02/01/18 1:07:00 PM",
           "02/01/18 1:08:00 PM" ,"02/01/18 1:09:00 PM",
           "02/01/18 1:10:00 PM" ,"02/01/18 1:11:00 PM")

x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
y <- c(11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,100,111,112)

datfr <- data.frame(dates, x, y)

datfr$dates <- dmy_hms(datfr$dates)
```

Intro
========================================================================

Inputs {.sidebar}
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```{r}
dateRangeInput('dateSelect', 'Date Range', start ="2018-01-01",
               end = "2018-01-02", min = "2018-01-01",
               max = "2018-01-02", format = "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Outputs
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart


```{r}
dateRange <- reactive({
  datfr %>%
  filter(dates >= input$dateSelect[1] & dates <= input$dateSelect[2])
})

renderPlot({
  ggplot(dateRange(), aes(datfr$x, datfr$y)) +
    geom_point()
})

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `aes(x, y)` rather than `aes(datfr$x, datfr$y)` otherwise you are not using the values from the reactive `dateRange` object, you are always using the values from the original `datfr` object.

Comment: Hmm..If I use `aes(x,y)` th plot is empty.

Comment: It works for me. When exactly does it become empty? Are you shooting the same date for the start and end? You seem to be comparing date values to date-time values. Dates are assumed to be at midnight. So you are probably just doing the wrong comparison in your filter.

Comment: Yes, you are right.Thanks.(upv).I noticed also, that if I use in `dateRangeInput` , `end = max(datfr$dates)` instead of `end = "2018-01-02"` the "to" date is empty and doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
dateRange <- reactive({
  datfr %>%
    mutate(dates = as.Date(as.character(dates))) %>%
    filter(dates >= input$dateSelect[1] & dates <= input$dateSelect[2])
})
```

And `aes(x, y)` as suggested by the other response here.